# Convergence of product of random variables with distribution $U(0, e)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0, e]$. Let $R_n:=\prod_{k=1}^n X_k$. By Kolmogorov's zero–one law $(R_n)$ converges with probability $0$ or $1$. I want to determine this probability.

Observe that $\log(R_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \log(X_k)$ with $\mathbb{E}[\log(X_k)]=0$ so, by the strong law of large numbers, $\log(R_n)/n\to 0$ almost surely. Moreover, by [Kolmogorov's three-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem), $\log(R_n)$ converges almost never. Unfortunately this does not imply that $R_n$ converges almost never. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence is almost surely non-convergent.

Assume the sequence was convergent. By the Hewitt-Savage zero-one law the limiting random variable has to be constant.

If the limit isn't zero, we can apply the continuous mapping theorem and we get that $\log(R_n)$ converges almost surely to a constant. This is a contradiction, since $\frac{\log(R_n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges weakly to a Gaussian distribution by the central limit theorem.

If the limit is zero, we use again that $\frac{\log(R_n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to a (centered) Gaussian random variable. This implies that $P(R_n > 1) = P(\log(R_n) > 0)$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$, in contradiction to the almost sure convergence of $R_n$ to $0$.

**Edit:** This can actually be simplified significantly. Since $\frac{\log(R_n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges weakly to a centered nondegenerate Gaussian random variable, the probability $P(n^{-1/2} \log(R_n) > 1) = P(R_n > \exp(\sqrt{n}))$ converges to a stricly positive number. But this means that $R_n$ isn't tight and therefore doesn't even have a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: I know that the limiting random variable has to be constant, but I don't see how you use Hewitt-Savage zero-one law to prove it. Can you explain it in more detail, please?

Comment: The Hewitt-Savage zero-one law states that the exchangeable $\sigma$-algebra is $P$-trivial. The limiting random variable is measurable with respect to the exchangeable $\sigma$-algebra and therefore constant. Note that in any polish space the only random variables that are measurable with respect to a $P$-trivial $\sigma$-algebra are constant.

Comment: I've added a simpler solution that doesn't need to consider different cases.

Comment: Thanks! Did you use Prokhorov's theorem in your last assertion, right?

Comment: You can use prohorov's theorem, but it's not really necessary. It's easy to see that every weakly convergent sequence is tight and the limit implies that $R_n$ has no tight subsequence.